# HTML a tag click event with action and calling the method in PHP

Tags: php, html, function, controller, action

Here is a maybe simple question for you however complicated question for me. Since i am beginner I need to obtain and learn this quickly. I have asked similar question yesterday but it was not the thing that i wanted. I am wondering about is there a way to handle the  tag on HTML handle the click event with PHP action and function.

On my 'Action.php' file I have a piece of code where the action is created:

```
$ARRAY_ACTION ["Frontend_upgradeChosen"] = array(

  "VIEW" =>"upgrade/upgrade.view.php",
   "VIEW_ERROR" => "error.php", 
    "TAB" => "UPGRADES",
    "SUBTAB"=>"",
    "AREA" => "GLOBAL",
    "WITHOUT_CONNECTION" => TRUE
);
```

On the other hand here is my 'upgrade.view.php' where i am populating the a tag with list tag and inside the  tags with the echo and for loop.

```
 <form class="" role="form" method="POST" action='index.php?action=Frontend_upgradeChosen'>

       <?
           echo '<li><a href="index.php?action=Frontend_upgradeChosen" name="PRODUCT" >'."Click Me".'</a></li>';

        ?>


    </form>
```

And finally here is my 'Controller.php' file and upgradeSearch function please forgive me but this question is crucial for me.

```
 public function upgradeChosen (){          
       $chosenProduct = $_GET['PRODUCT'];        
       var_dump ($chosenProduct);    
       include $this->getPrintedView();
}
```

I can succesfully can populate tags, however i can not achieve the click event. I know it is possible with javascript but i do not want to do it in that manner i need to create an action as given the example above and i need to handle the click event of  link tag. Please any help of suggestions on this I will be happy and you will save my life.

Thanks in advance

Here is the edited version lastly what i want to achieve is to when i can click on [Click Me] i want to fire the upgradeChosen Function and handle the clikc event of  tag. the error that i am getting is

Notice: Undefined index: PRODUCT in ------- on line 1151
NULL

Comment: to use `$_POST` your form must be submitted. Are you submitting your form??

Comment: Yeah the form is posted successfully and i can get the list but for some reason i do not know how to handle click event thanks

Comment: `click event`?? on click of what??

Comment: I have indicated on what but for some reason i has gone can you see the line under the foreach loop it starts with echo '<li><a and goes i want to handle a click event on <a> tag with php action

Comment: on click of `<a>` you cant post the data. only you can use `$_GET`.

Comment: so inside the form i need to post my data and get the method on click of a yeah can you give me an example please to be more clear

Comment: if you want to use `$_POST`, your form should be submitted. If you want to access php code from a like, try using `$_GET`.

Comment: echo '<li><a href="index.php?action=Frontend_upgradeChosen" name="PRODUCT" >'."Click me".'</a></li>';
 public function upgradeChosen (){
        
        $chosenProduct = $_GET['PRODUCT'];
            
            var_dump ($chosenProduct);
    
        include $this->getPrintedView();
    }
I am doing something like this but it is not working

Comment: Undefined index: PRODUCT in

Comment: `action` you are passing this. So `$_GET['PRODUCT']` is throwing error.

Comment: btw i have created another action for this specifically

Comment: yes it is thorwing error

Comment: What error are you getting??

Comment: I made the code more shorter and i have written about my error thanks a lot

Comment: it returns NULL object for some reason come on guys need help urgently please

Comment: the problem i have noticed that i can not get the value of a tag where it is not possible i can handle the click event but i can not choose the value....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To get value from one page to another page in php, we should use `GET` or `POST`.

**Question**

When to use `GET` and `POST`

**POST**

To use post you have to submit the form.

```
<form method="post" action="abc.php">
     <input name="username" type="text" />
</form>
```

To access the username,

```
$username = $_POST['username'];// this will give you what user has entered in the textbox.
```

Now you can also use `GET` as method in form.

```
$username = $_GET['username'];// this will give you what user has entered in the textbox.
```

Both the above methods are example for getting value on form submit.

Now if you want to get values on click of `<a>` tag, how to do??

use **GET**

**Example**

```
<a href="abc.php?username=user"></a>
```

in php

```
$username = $_GET['username'];// this will give you had given in a tag
```

For multiple values in a tag,

```
<a href="abc.php?username=user&password=111111"></a>
```

in php

```
$username = $_GET['username'];// this will give you had given in a tag
$password = $_GET['password'];// this will give you had given in a tag
```

There is one more thing called `REQUEST`, which will have the values of both `POST` and `GET`

Read about

- [POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)
- [GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)
- [REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)

Comment: many thanks for your good explanation and your time to explain it this clearly, i have found this solution in somewhere else, however i have noticed that this not the thing that i want to obtain is it possible to get the value of click me or adding value attribute inside the A tag and parse the value of it because everytime the data will change with the for loop.. Many thanks in advance

Comment: how the submission will be completed in my case with a button ?

Comment: Dear Niranjan many thanks for your help i could manage the submit the form and get the value by changing the a tag to option tag cheers for your help

Comment: If the answer was helpful, consider accepting it.:)